# Change temp directory where Thunderbird stores attachments when opening them

Tags: email, thunderbird, attachments, temporary-files

Using **Thunderbird 38.5.1** on Windows, I sometimes double-click on an attachment in a received message to open it.

The file is saved to my temp directory (`%TEMP%`), but I don't want it to be saved to that location (even temporarily). How do I change the directory Thunderbird uses for this?

If there isn't a built-in setting for it, is it possible to somehow override the `TEMP` environment variable for Thunderbird only?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a batch file to override the environment variable, as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036367/1536933

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Thunderbird seems to use TMP, but override both to be sure
SET TMP=M:\y\Temp\Dir
SET TEMP=%TMP%
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```

Change the shortcut to call this batch file, set it to run Minimized (to avoid the command prompt window popping up) and it works quite smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux: [Thunderbird cannot open attachments under Linux any more after updating](https://superuser.com/questions/1276256/thunderbird-cannot-open-attachments-under-linux-any-more-after-updating/1276257#answer-1607150)

It may be required under Linux to open attachments with double-click.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. But, IMO, the link ***doesn’t*** answer this question — the question is about Windows, and your answer (as you say) is about Linux.