# Thunderbird cannot open attachments under Linux any more after updating

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, app-armor

I use Debian unstable. After updating the system, Thunderbird suddenly cannot open attachments any more -- nothing happens at all, but the file is stored in `/tmp/mozilla...`.  Usually, `evince` (or `firefox-bin`, aka Firefox quantum) would open normally on my computer.

Opening Thunderbird through the command line, following error messages are printed:

```
(thunderbird:25364): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/jenserat/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Datei »/home/jenserat/.local/share/recently-used.xbel« konnte nicht geöffnet werden: Keine Berechtigung.

(thunderbird:25364): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/jenserat/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Keine Berechtigung

(thunderbird:25364): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/jenserat/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Keine Berechtigung

(thunderbird:25364): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/jenserat/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Datei »/home/jenserat/.local/share/recently-used.xbel« konnte nicht geöffnet werden: Keine Berechtigung.
```

("Keine Berechtigung" is German for "Permission denied")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is triggered by a mix of a recent Debian kernel now supporting App Armor, and the App Armor rules shipped with the system being to strict and denying `evince` to access the recently used files (which are updated when opening an attachment with `evince`). The issue is also described in [Debian bug report #882782](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882782) and might as well affect other Linux distributions.

The solution is to install the App Armor tools package (`sudo apt install apparmor-utils` and then adjusting the App Armor profile using `sudo aa-logprof`). The tool will show following observations (likely it will print more results which will indicate other issues, in my case it was the first):

```
$ sudo aa-logprof
Reading log entries from /var/log/audit/audit.log.
Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.

Profile:  thunderbird
Execute:  /usr/bin/evince
Severity: unknown

(I)nherit / (C)hild / (P)rofile / (N)amed / (U)nconfined / (X) ix On / (D)eny / Abo(r)t / (F)inish
```

The output means that while the `thunderbird` profile was active, `/usr/bin/evince` was to be executed but failed.

You can now decide whether to:

- (**I**)nherit Thunderbird's profile (which means Thunderbird's restrictions will also apply to `evince`, which will not be matching properly), or
- (**C**)hild will apply `evince`'s profile instead (if available)  <-- that's what we're looking for.

  ...
- Finally, select (**F**)inish to finish editing.

If you use another tool to read logs, the prompt might read slightly different.

Future Thunderbird updates should bring better App Armor profiles, but this is a proper workaround for the moment (and should not do harm in future after better profiles are installed).

---

*It's worth noting that the man page for `aa-logprof` only mentions this menu:*

> (A)llow,  (D)eny, (I)gnore,  (N)ew, (G)lob last piece, (Q)uit

*but it doesn't seem to apply to this situation. Perhaps the man page will be updated at some point to better explain this.*

Comment: For me, that unfortunately gives:
`sudo aa-logprof`

`ERROR: Values added to a non-existing variable @{HOMEDIRS}: /home/*redacted*/ in tunables/home.d/*redacted*`
Probably related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1331856

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, the cause may be that you have snapd version
of Thunderbird or other application opening attachment.

In that case, according to [that](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/sharing-files-via-tmp/1613/22) thread:

> /tmp isn’t “the global and universally accessible location” any more

As a solution,
you must override the `TMP` environment variable for Thunderbird process. 
Make a file called, for example, `~/bin/thunderbird`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TMP=$HOME/Downloads /usr/bin/thunderbird "$@"
```

make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/thunderbird
```

Now you should be able to double-click attachments
and open them with other snapd apps like Chromium or OpenOffice.

Comment: (1) If you didn’t mean “snapd”, please [edit] your answer to clarify what you are talking about. I can’t find anything called “snaped”. (2) The sentence that you quote isn’t in the document you linked to. Can you provide a valid reference? (3) Please learn the difference between `$*` and `$@`, and don’t use `$*` except in the very few cases where it’s appropriate.